# React Native on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-emulator

I am not sure if I am doing this right. I have gone to the React Native website and now it looks like they are attempting to force you to use Expo which I do not want to use at this point. I was not able to find any information on running an Android simulator. I have installed Android Studio, I then start the emulator, run react-native run-android, and I get the following error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can test my code for Android?

[image]

Comment: i think the java version and gradle version can't work well .my environment is gradle 2.4.1 java 1.8 android 2.3.2

Comment: did you set system environment variable

Comment: About that, I do not know where to point my environmental variable. I cannot even find an Android SDK for MAC. All I can find are the tools located at the bottom of the page https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html . I attempt to point Genymotion to this file and it does not recognize this as an SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The work around for this was to use a different version of the mobile emulator. I was trying to use Nexus. I deleted the Nexus and installed a Galaxy and everything worked. The discussion regarding this issue can be read in the included link:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2720

Answer (score -1):

React Native does not force you to use Expo. Did you follow the directions for [Android Setup](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)?

Also [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) is much easier to set up than stock Google emulators.

Comment: This was the url I found for React Native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/ . I did not find the one you posted.

Comment: I believe the page you linked to is not good anymore. Home-brew for one does not support installing SDK anymore. Google seems to be trying to phase out using the SDK for using Android Studio. I tried following the instruction by going from one issue that came up to the next and ended up with the same result.

Comment: You are right I corrected my link to point to the latest instructions. Did you try googleing that specific error?

Comment: Yes I did. I spend half of yesterday trying to fix it with tidbits from several posts. None worked for me. I also tried Genymotion and had the same error. Not really sure where to go with this. When I get back to work tomorrow I plan of plugging an android into my computer to see if that works. Thats not too helpful though.

Comment: Funny thing is I tried it with Expo as well and ran into entirely different errors. lol

Comment: Genymotion never sends me a password/key so I can't use it. Bluestacks looks like it's going to work but doesn't try to simulated the dimensions etc of a phone.